# Auction Theory: Proving that the found equilibrium is indeed optimal

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, auctions

I have been looking at auction theory and in the book Auction Theory by Krishna, there is one (seemingly simple) inequality that I just cannot follow.

Context: given a private valuation $x$, the optimal bidding strategy has been found $\beta(x)$. Now, the author wants to show that behaving and bidding as if you were of type $z$, $\beta(z)$ does not increase profits.
Then, calculating the difference between the profit in the optimum and the profit if you would behave as if you were of type $z$ leads to the following inequality.
$G(x)$ being a probability distriubtion:
$$\pi(\beta(x),x) - \pi( \beta(z),x) = G(z)(z-x) - \int_x^zG(y)dy \geq 0$$

The profit functions were calculated from a first-price auction in case it helps anyone.
My question is why the inequality holds. Why is $G(z)(z-x) - \int_x^zG(y)dy$ larger than 0?

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
G(z) (z-x) =
\int_x^z G(z) dy
$$
and since $G$ is increasing on $[x,z]$, the right hand side is larger than
$\int_x^z G(y) dy$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you perhaps also know why the equation hold for the case where z<x? That is for me the most confusing part of the inequality... @Giskard

Comment: @Snowrabbit Same reason. In that case $G(z)$ is smaller than $G(y)$ for all $y \in [z,x]$ and $(z-x)<0$.

Comment: Now I see it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Although there already is an accepted answer, there is another way to see the global optimality - or rather the same way with a different formulation.

By construction,
$$\frac{\partial \pi}{\partial b}(b,x) = - G((\beta)^{-1}(b)) + (x-b)
\frac{G'((\beta)^{-1}(b))}{(\beta)'((\beta)^{-1}(b))}\Bigg{|}_{b=\beta(x)}= 0,$$
where $\frac{\partial \pi}{\partial b}(b,x)$ is increasing in $x$.

Now consider some bid $\widehat b<\beta(x)$.
By continuity of $\beta$, there is a type $\widehat x<x$ such that $\beta(\widehat x)=\widehat b$.
Hence, because $\widehat  x<x$,
$$\frac{\partial \Pi}{\partial b}(\widehat b,x) \geq \frac{\partial \Pi}{\partial b}(\widehat b, \widehat x) = \frac{\partial \Pi}{\partial b} (\beta(\widehat x),\widehat x) = 0. $$
Thus, the expected utility $\Pi( b,x)$ is increasing in $b$ for all $  b<\beta(x)$.
Analogously, $\Pi(b,x)$ is decreasing for all $\widehat b'>\beta(x)$.